# How can I share and use just one RAM module in multiple modules?

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I want to write a module in RAM and then read from the same into another module. How can I do this? I think there must be a way to pass RAM modules by referencing to other modules. For example:

In module A:

```
// write in ram and pass to module B

ram ram_ins();
ram_ins.wr_en = 1;
ram_ins.addr = 1;
ram_ins.data_in = 1234;
B b_ins(ram_ins); // pass by reference the ram_ins to the module B
```

In module B:

```
// read from ram 

ram_ins.addr = 1;
reg [7:0] a;
assign a = ram_ins.data_out
```

Register `a` in module B must be 1234, because in module A 1234 is written in address 1 of RAM.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "pass RAM modules by referencing" Do you want a single RAM which is written to by 1 module and read by another? Do you have separate write address and read address ports.

Comment: Verilog is a Hardware Description Language (HDL). HDLs behave completely different from normal programming languages. Usually there is no concept of pointers and references. There is only the concept of wires or signals as in real life circuits. I would advice to read a few tutorials on how to build simple modules in Verilog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to RAM from other modules you need some control module for this or communication bus. For example Altera UFM I2C interface. RAM can be write by module A and read by module B with different clocks (Dual-ported RAM):

http://www.asic-world.com/examples/verilog/ram_dp_sr_sw.html

http://www.asic-world.com/examples/verilog/ram_dp_ar_aw.html

At a certain level of abstraction I2C device address is your reference.

Sorry for My English.

Answer (score 1):

One Ram cannot be accessed by two different modules. What you need is a module to arbitrate between the accesses I'll just show the write path for simplicity i.e.:

```
module ram ( 
    input clk,
    input wr,
    input [7:0] data
);
///Ram model here
endmodule

module arbiter (
input clk,
input rst_n,


output ram_wr,
output [7:0] ram_data,

output [1:0] write_accepted,

input m0_wr,
input [7:0] m0_data,
input m1_wr,
input [7:0] m1_data,
);
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
if (!rst_n) 
  current <= 1'b0;
else
  current <= !current;

assign ram_data = current ? m1_data : m0_data;
assign write_accepted = {(current & m1_wr),(!current & m1_wr)};
assign ram_wr = |write_accepted;
endmodule
```

So many reasons I wouldn't want to ship a chip with that code in, but hopefully you get the idea.